# Call Success Dialog from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

i want to call the Success or Error Dialog from Laravel in Javascript! I have an Ajax Post Request like this:

```
$.post('/tutorials/rate', {id:tutID, rating : rating});
```

How can i call the Dialog from that Ajax Method?! In my Controller i always did it like that:

```
return Redirect::to('/tutorials/show/' . $postId)->with('success', 'Successfully Rated!');
```

EDIT: My Question is how to call that line:

```
return Redirect::to('/tutorials/show/' . $postId)->with('success', 'Successfully Rated!');
```

in Javascript!

Solved it by adding:

```
    $.pnotify({
title: 'No Icon Success',
text: 'I have no icon.',
type: 'success',
icon: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no tag for jQuery but you use `$.post` which is one of jQuery's functions so im going to assume that till noted otherwise.

`.post` has a third optional parameter where you can set the callback function, either use the name of a function or use an anonymous function.

```
$.post('/tutorials/rate', {id:tutID, rating : rating},function(dialogHTML){
   //Do whatever code shows your dialog
   var dlg = jQuery(dialogHTML);
   jQuery('body').append(dlg);
   dlg.fadeIn();
},'html');
```

OR

```
$.post('/tutorials/rate', {id:tutID, rating : rating},myCallback);

function myCallback(dialogHTML) {
   //Do whatever code shows your dialog
   var dlg = jQuery(dialogHTML);
   jQuery('body').append(dlg);
   dlg.fadeIn();
}
```

[jQuery .post api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: create the Dialog in the page that has this script and then just display it when needed, in this case from the callback. For instance create the dialog html and give the dialog a id of like `successDialog` and do like `$('#successDialog').fadeIn();`

Comment: Yes, thats possible...But with a Postback i don´t have to create this dialof by myself, i thought it´s possible to call this ready dialog from javascript, too!

Comment: if the script that your post is calling returns the dialog html then you can retrieve the html by adding a fourth parameter `'html'` and using it in the callback, edited the answer to show that. If it doesnt at the moment just add the laravel php code that will display a dialog and output the html. And use the edits i added about getting the html.

Answer (score 0):

You would call it like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/tutorials/rate',
  data: parameters,
  success: function(){
    alert('success');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('failure');
  }
});
```